# applyMiddleware works only if the file is commenJS , not working in ES6 file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Iam trying to use applyMiddleware from redux but when I edit package.json file

( adding =>  `"type" : "module"` ) to use ES6 to import applyMiddleware  as following

`import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";`,

I have that ERROR

```
\node_modules\redux\lib\redux.js:671
        return middleware(middlewareAPI);
               ^

TypeError: middleware is not a function
```

but when I remove (  `"type" : "module"`  ) from package.json file and import applyMiddleware as following

```
const redux = require("redux");
const createStore = redux.createStore;
const applyMiddleware = redux.applyMiddleware;
```

it works fine. why applyMiddleware works only with commenJS and how to make it works with type module.